# class for database connection with pdo

Tags: php, database, pdo

```
<?php
class Database{
    private $hostdb="localhost";
    private $userdb = "root";
    private $passdb = "";
    private $namedb = "database"
    public $pdo;

    public function __construct(){
        if(!isset($this->pdo)) {
            try{
                $link = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->hostdb.";dbname=".$this->namedb, $this->userdb, $this->passdb);
                $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $link->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
                $this->pdo = $link;
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die("failed to connect with database".$e->getMessage());
            }   

        }
    }
}
```

?>`

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\lr\lib\Database.php on line 7

Answer (score -1):

Missing semicolon:

```
private $namedb = "database" ; // <--
```